# Crystal Reports different margins for different printers

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

when i print a crystal report on two printers - it appears different.

On printer one , the bottom margin is rather small, consistently - close to 3/16ths - as it needs to be.

On printer two, the bottom margin is larger, closer to 5/16ths. How can I get these printers to have the same small margin

One printer is a HP LaserJet P3015 printer and the other is a HP LaserJet P4015 printer

Comment: are you printing A4?

Comment: @ yes the paper size is A4. if relevant, they are both set to any size for dimension and type

Comment: Inside Crystal designer -> Printer Settings screen, there is an checkbox for Automatically adjust to ... I cant remember what exactly, but I have used it quite often